# Calculating on time values

Tags: sql, datetime, excel, vba

I've got many rows of racing lap times stored in Excel in the following format:

> 1:32.9

This example would mean the lap time was 1 minute, 32 and nine tenths of a second.

To preserve my data I keep the values formatted as text in excel and I'm uploading (via some rookie excel vba code) to a sql azure db into a field formatted as nvarchar (25).

I want to perform mathematical computation on the values. Primarily basic arithmetic functions, averages and some simple statistical analysis.

Given this, what are the suggestions for dealing with this data? Given my limited sql knowledge at this point I can see the following options:

1. Somehow convert the value to all seconds (example above would become 92.9 sec) and store in a sql column formatted as decimal (can I do this in T-SQL and just build a view?)
2. Somehow convert the value to a time formatted field, however Im unclear what my computation options will be if I do this

I can incorporate the translation in Excel vba during the upload processing or in T-sql, although it would be great if I could work it into a view definition and run my reports from that.

Suggestions for the right way to handle this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it via excel formula and set the value to a different excel sheet column and then load to the SQL Table.

If this is not feasible, then you can load the data to a table and then define a view adapting the following query:

```
WITH DummyData AS
(
  SELECT '1:32.9' TimeText -- This can be replaced with the table that you loaded.
)
SELECT CAST(
        DATEPART(mi, '00:' + TimeText) * 60 +
        DATEPART(ss, '00:' + TimeText)
         AS VARCHAR
        )+ '.' +
       CAST( DATEPART(ms, '00:' + TimeText) AS VARCHAR)
  FROM DummyData
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/2349/0

Comment: Thanks for the help, that ended up working although it took me a bit to figure out. Uploading Time format from Excel into SQL is not easy so I used this query. Biggest issue was that I had some laptimes in the data that did not have values - had to make sure the SELECT query filtered those out. This query translates '1:32.9' to '92.900', which is the total in seconds. Thanks again.

Comment: One last note...the query above created by 92.900, but that was still varchar. Enclosing the 'SELECT CAST...' statement with an additional CAST level to change the final value to numeric was required to be able to perform mathematical functions.